# Is it possible to insert all but the last separator when printing from a Python 3 for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

Please see the below example for the sake of a clear question:

This syntax:

```
print('a','b','c',sep=' @ ')
```

yields this output:

```
a @ b @ c
```

This is the output that I want to yield, but from within a for loop.

The attempts that I have made so far are:

```
for item in ['a','b','c']:
    print(item,sep=' @ ')
```

but this yields:

```
a
b
c
```

and:

```
for item in ['a','b','c']:
    print(item,end=' @ ')
```

but this yields:

```
a @ b @ c @
```

Is there a way to produce the output:

```
a @ b @ c
```

from this for loop specifically?

*** Further clarification since it seems the details are important for the answer ***

The full set up is as follows:

```
for fruit in df.index.year.unique():
    total = df[df.index.year == year]['Number of Fruits'].sum()
    print(fruit + ' Total: ' + str(total))
```

and I specifically want to print each fruit and total on the same line separated by a ' | ', but without the ' | ' separator appearing at the end.

Thanks!

Comment: `' @ '.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])` is IMO the most pythonic.

Comment: I think this is a fair point.  I shall look it over again and decide.  Either way, thanks for help all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the reason you want to use a loop is because you want to print an arbitrary number of items with separators, then you can use `print` with unpacking.

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(*lst, sep=' @ ') # 'a @ b @ c'
```

Since a single IO call is faster than using `print` in a for-loop, there is no real reason not to use it.

As for the specific use case you provided, here is how you would adapt the above solution.

```
lst = []

for fruit in df.index.year.unique():
    total = df[df.index.year == year]['Number of Fruits'].sum()
    lst.append('{} Total: {}'.format(fruit, total))

print(*lst, sep=' @ ')
```

Comment: I am not sure that this works for my specific use case, though it does seem to be the most pythonic answer so far.  Some clarification pending from me...

Comment: @agftrading what is your specific use case? I really see no case where the list cannot be generated beforehand and then printed this way.

Comment: Thanks.  I have updated the question with further details.  I think the problem in the specific case is that the print statement requires some text concatenation.  This might make deploying your solution more problematic?  Please let me know if you think it still works!

Comment: @agftrading You have to generate the list first, that's all. See the edit.

Comment: @DudeCoder It's not faster complexity-wise. It's just that IO call are very expensive and unpacking arguments in the print call format the whole string and then does a single IO call.

Comment: And in addition to that your code will take more memory too, as you're making another list over here

Comment: That solution makes sense and seems the cleanest!  I have marked it as the best answer.  However, indeed it would be preferable to avoid making and appending to the new list.  Any other suggestions that avoid this are welcome!

Comment: @agftrading If you have a dataframe in memory already, this really will not be a bottleneck memory-wise. I think trying to keep IO calls to a minimum is generally a good choice performance wise, but if you really do not want an intermediate list stored, then [Vicrobot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50828934/5079316) offers a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one if you want your result with a `for` loop:-

```
t = ['a','b','c']
for i in t[:-1]:
    print(i, end=' @ ')
print(t[-1])
```

Also the `sep` didn't work because it separates two or more elements; and can't do that on one element.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on why the sep did not work in the for loop!  I was wondering specifically about that!  Helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can let the loop print one more `@` at end, after that just remove that from screen like so:

```
for i in ['a','b','c']:
  print(i, end=' @ ')
print('\b\b ')
```

`\b` is used to move cursor one place before and then a there is a space in the `print` command, so that the last `@` will be overwritten with a space, and no longer will be visible

You can see that code in action over here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
lst1 = ['a','b','c']
for item in lst1:
    print(item,end=' @ \n')
```

Output:

```
a @ 
b @ 
c @
```

Use end instead of seperator for the desired output. Hopefully, it's helpful!!

Comment: the desired output is `a @ b @ c`